# Loop that will check network connection using tkinter and urllib

Tags: python, tkinter, urllib

```
import urllib
import urllib.request as url
from tkinter import *

master = Tk()
master.geometry("250x50")
master.resizable(False, False)
master.config(bg="#4b4b4b")
master.overrideredirect(True)
master.wm_geometry("-0-40")

connectStatus = Label(bg="yellow", fg="#fff", width=28, height=2, text="Pending", font="Bahnscrift 10")
connectStatus.place(x=10,y=8)

def runRefresh():
    print("Checking")
    connectStatus.config(bg="yellow", fg="#fff", width=28, height=2, text="Pending", font="Bahnscrift 10")
    attemptConnect()

def attemptConnect():
    try:
        ping = url.urlopen("https://stackoverflow.com", timeout=1)
        connectStatus.config(text="Connected", font="Bahnscrift 10", bg="green")
        return True

    except urllib.error.URLError:
        connectStatus.config(text="Not Connected", bg="#ff4d4d", font="Bahnscrift 10")
        return False

master.after(1000, runRefresh)
master.mainloop()
```

Hello. I'm using the following code - what this code does currently is runs the attemptConnect() function and changes the Label accordingly (depending on what happens in the try/except). The problem I'm having is getting this to loop every couple of seconds.. I can't figure out a way to do it. I've tried using tkinter's after, but nothing..

So my question - How can I get this to run the attemptConnect() every couple of seconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

currently, your code calls `runRefresh` just once after the mainloop .

modify `runRefresh` to :

```
def runRefresh():
        print("Checking")
        connectStatus.config(bg="yellow", fg="#fff", width=28, height=2, text="Pending", font="Bahnscrift 10")
        attemptConnect()
        master.after(1000, runRefresh)
```

so that runRefresh calls itself recursively every 1 second